# sbt ivy2: configuration 'master' not found from 'compile'

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I am getting the following error when I build a library `bp-kafka-bp2` that depends on library `bp-bp2-componentized`:

> sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   com.foo#bp-bp2-componentized_2.11;3.3.+: configuration not found in
>   com.foo#bp-bp2-componentized_2.11;3.3.0: 'master'. It was required
>   from com.foo#bp-kafka-bp2_2.11;3.10.1 compile

The unresolved library `bp-bp2-componentized` does in fact exist in `~/.ivy2/local` and does not have a `master` configuration in its `ivy.xml`

My questions are:

1. Should the dependent library (bp-kafka-bp2) be looking for a `master` configuration of the (not really) missing library?
2. If it should not be looking for a `master` config, what can I do to make it stop doing so?
3. If it should be looking for a `master` config, how do I induce the build for the (not really) missing library to produce such a config?

I have tried this in `sbt` versions `1.1.5` and `1.2.1`. I have deleted `~/.ivy2/local`, `./ivy2/cache` and `~/.sbt`.  I have also removed all the `/target` and `project/target` directories in the library I am building and done `sbt clean`

This library has built just fine for a year or two now.  The only recent change I can think of is introducing 2.11 and 2.12 cross-compilation option -- which is not being exercised here, I'm just building 2.11 version on its own.

The direct dependency is declared in a multi-project build.sbt as

```
lazy val bp2 = (project in file("bp2")).
  settings(commonSettings:_*).
  settings(Seq(
    name := "bp-kafka-bp2"
  ):_*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % ScalaTestVersion % "test",
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % LogbackVersion % "test",
      "com.foo" %% "bp-bp2-componentized" % Constellation.dependency("bp-bp2"),
      "com.foo" %% "bp-akka-http" % Constellation.dependency("bp-akka")
    )
  ).
  dependsOn(reactiveComponentized)
```

where `Constellation.dependency` is just a function that looks up a version by name and turns it into a patch range:

```
object Constellation {
  ...  
  def dependency(name: String) : String = versions(name).split("\\.").dropRight(1).mkString(".") + ".+"
}
```

You can see from the error message that the version is being found and converted to `3.3.+` which is then resolved correctly to a `3.3.0` in the `ivy` cache.  But then it insists on finding a `master` configuration which is not present.

Comment: How are those dependencies declared? Can you show the relevant part of the `build.sbt`?

Comment: @laughedelic thanks for taking a look.  I've aded the declared dependency to the question body.